# isotope.js reLayout method not working when removing first item in a list

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope.js to display images in a simple cms, and when an image is deleted it removes the image from the list i'm calling the reLayout method:

```
$('.item').on('click',function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('ul').isotope( 'reLayout' );
    });
```

This works for every single item except the first item in the list.

I've replicated the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FgVLV/2/

Can anyone help me out here? I can't figure it out for the life of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out. There is a remove method in isotope that does what i was doing manually. All's well that ends well. Here's the documentation for you future people who might need it:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#remove

Answer (score 0):

```
//#container_+id is container element
$obj = $('#container_'+id); //VERY IMPORTANT!

$('#container_'+id).animate({
    opacity: 0,
    height: 'toggle'                
}, 1000, function() {
    elem_isotope.isotope('remove', $obj);
    $("#container_" + id).remove();
    $.when($("#container_" + id).remove()).then( elem_isotope.isotope('reLayout'));

});
```